# Convex function on an open interval

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

Consider the $f:I \subseteq \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined on an open interval $I$ and which is twice differentiable. The following properties are equivalent:

$(1)$ $f$ is convex over $I$.

$(2)$ For every $x \in I$ is $f''(x) \geq 0$.

I am given a proof on this, but there is one step that I don't quite understand. It concerns the implication $(1) \rightarrow (2)$: "Suppose that $f$ is convex. Take a random $x \in I$. As $I$ is open, we can take a $\delta >0$ so that $]x- \delta ,x+ \delta [ \subseteq I$. Because $f$ is convex,  $\frac{f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)}{h^{2}} \geq 0$ for every $h \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0< \vert h \vert < \delta$. If we take the limit of that inequality for $h \rightarrow 0$, we find that $f''(x) \geq 0$."

My question: why does the convexness of $f$ imply $\frac{f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)}{h^{2}} \geq 0$ for every $h \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0< \vert h \vert < \delta$ ?

Comment: By the definition of convex function, the numerator is nonnegative.
$$\frac{f(x-h)+f(x+h)}{2} \ge \;??$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition of convex is $\lambda f( a)+(1-\lambda)f(b)\ge f(\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b) \forall a,b,\lambda$. Applying this with $a=x+h,b=x-h,\lambda=1/2$ gives $f(x+h)+f(x-h)\ge 2f(x)$ which leads directly to the conclusion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Though I would like to know how this follows from the other definition of convex; for every $x,y$ and every $\lambda \in [0,1]$ it holds that $f((1- \lambda )x+ \lambda y) \leq (1- \lambda )f(x)+ \lambda f(y)$?

Comment: My bad, I had the wrong definition... it should be $f((1- \lambda )x+ \lambda y) \leq (1- \lambda )f(x)+ \lambda f(y)$

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is convex so $\frac{1}{2}f(a)+ \frac{1}{2}f(b)\ge f(\frac{a+b}{2}) \quad \forall a,b \in R$

Now plug $a=x+h,b=x-h$  you get $$\frac{f(x+h)+f(x-h)}{2}\ge f(x)$$